# How to search line by line and return matched lines in C++

Tags: c++

I need to search for a key word like "stack overflow" in an std::string and return all lines where string was found.

So my std::string might look like this,

```
ghfhfhfhf dghfhf dtgd \n
dgdhfghfgfh  stack overflow \n
stack overflow dgdfgdgdg  \n
dgdgh dgdrgdrgdg  \n
stack overflow dffdbdb  \n
```

Notice, there are multiple lines in this std::string with "\n" indicating end of line. I was making a function that will search for "stack overflow" and it will return a vector of strings that contains all the lines with a match.

For example, return vector will look like,

```
v[0]  dgdhfghfgfh  stack overflow \n
v[1]  stack overflow dgdfgdgdg  \n
v[2]  stack overflow dffdbdb  \n
```

The goal is to know how many lines had the hit and what did that line look like. Can someone please help me with this?

This needs to run on Linux Redhat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put each line into a `std::string` and, using `find("stack overflow")`, search for the substring. Once it is found, push it into the vector:

```
while (std::getline(file, line))
{
    if (line.find("stack overflow") != line.end())
        v.push_back(line);
}
```

The above also works for strings if you wrap your string into a `std::stringstream` and use that in place of `file`.